# PHP Massive array split into two unique arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

First of all sorry for any mistakes that I make :)

Secondly, I have a problem with php array:
I have a table ( users ) which has 0,5 million users in it. I have to select every user email in there ( they are all unique emails ).

I have a file ( import.txt ) which contains 50k users. They all have unique emails too.

I have second table ( discounts ) which has users.id placed with my company_id ( every users.id is paired with company_id, so it can't repeat ).

Problem:

1. I have to check which of the import.txt emails is registered in the
   system and sort it ( to make a array which contains only registered
   users ).
2. Then i have to make an array which contains users which is
   not registered.
3. After that i have to check if the registered user id
   exist in my discounts table and remove it from array if ir exists.
   If it doesn't exist i have to insert it. ( it means that i have to get id for the email too and check if that id is in my discounts table or not )
4. Next thing is that i have an array which contains users who's not registered. This is bad because i have to do a curl POST request to receive user id ( in
   other words - register it via API ) and insert it into the discounts
   table.

Does anyone have any ideas how to make this script run fast? I had an idea of running multiple loops, but maybe there's a better solution for that?

Thank's in advance for the help!
If anything was not clear - please comment and I will fix it

Little scheme for better visualization: [Scheme link](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1JZNL0Bkt8a-4TdvobV7ICRJz5yZs4E4kOxS59aZM8-w/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'd import the text file into a temporary table and get the database to do the querying - it'll be a whole lot faster than doing it in PHP.

Comment: @MikeW - Any examples for that? :) Because I have never tryed this before

Answer (score 0):

```
//this will generate an array of all emails in import.txt, assuming they are 1 per line
$emails = file('import.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

//this will create a string of the $emails array to use for an IN() SQL query
$emails_string = "'". implode("', '", $emails) ."'";

//this will give you all emails in imports.txt that are registered
$exists = $pdo->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email IN($emails_string)");

//this will give you all emails in imports.txt that are NOT registered
$not_exists = $pdo->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email NOT IN($emails_string)");
```

This should be a good start. You will probably have to end up using a foreach() loop for #3 and #4 though.

Comment: Problem is that it will run a database query with each email which is not very good

Comment: There is a danger with this approach that 50k email addresses will exceed the default packet size limit of 1Mb. That could be adjusted, but an IN clause with 50k entries won't be fast. A temporary table will be much faster.

Comment: I agree with Mike W, because running that much queries will flood my server.. And the fact that it's running at high percentage makes this thing even more inapropriate solution